# Qt OpenGL textures transparency issues

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm working on a viewer in Qt to show images with lines or text on top.
I have organized images, lines and text on several layers, each layer is a GL_QUADS.
If I stack images in z and then draw a layer on top with lines, it all  works as expected.
But I want to draw more lines on several other layers **at the same z** as the first lines layer, and that's the result:
[lines layers conflict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dKJE.png).

I don't understand why each lines layer erase previous overlapped lines layer (but don't corrupt underlying images).
Moreover if I draw another layer **at the same z** as lines layer but with some text, this is the result:
[text layer issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3jXI.png).

Text layer create a hole in all undelying layers and you can see the background.

Lines and text are painted with QPainter on a QImage this way:

```
m_img = new QImage(&m_buffer[0], width, height, QImage::Format_RGBA8888);
m_img->fill(Qt::transparent);

QPen pen(color);
pen.setWidth(2);
m_painter.begin(m_img);
m_painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
m_painter.setPen(pen);
m_painter.drawLines(lines);
m_painter.end();

QFont font;
int font_size = font.pointSize() * scale;
if (font_size > 0) { font.setPointSize(font_size); }
QPen pen(color);
m_painter.begin(m_img);
m_painter.setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
m_painter.setFont(font);
m_painter.setPen(pen);
for(int index = 0; index < messages.size(); index++)
    m_painter.drawText(positions.at(index), messages.at(index));
m_painter.end();
```

and textures:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, d->width(), d->height(), 0, GL_RGBA,  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, d->data());
```

This is my texture setup():

```
GLuint texture;
glGenTextures(1, &texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST/*GL_LINEAR*/);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST/*GL_LINEAR*/);
opengl_error_check(__FILE__, __LINE__);
```

This is my initializeGL():

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable (GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
```

Finally I have set QGLFormat(QGL::AlphaChannel) in my QGLWidget.

I know that there is a problem of z-fighting using overlapping planes at the same z, but as far as I know it should matter only if the overlapping textures are not transparent. In my case some artifacts may be expected where lines crosses, but I don't understand why lines disappear.
And since I use the same way to draw lines and text, I don't understand why text layer influence images while lines not.

Last note: I have printed pixel values in all textures right before glTexImage2D() and values are as expected.

I'm pretty sure there is some obvious mistake, can someone point me where I'm wrong?

Comment: Any other suggestion? I've tried with several blending options but did non work. Also ordering objects in painting process ignoring depth is not an option for my application...

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL works by "painter" principle. Unless you use Z-ordering (aka depth test), what is drawn last is drawn on top. It works like splattering paint on the wall, hence the term. Nota bene: depth test is off by default, in general, it does slow rendering down.

If you use Z-ordering,  OpenGL will "hide" fragments which fall into area of "window space" (color buffer), where "paint" with bigger Z value already exist. Thus , there is no depth-based  "automatic" transparency in OpenGL: **to emulate transparency you must paint things in proper order, with proper blending mode.** That may prove to be problem, if objects intersect or self-intersect. Creating complex scenes with transparency and shadows  requres technique called deferred rendering.

If you paint with same Z, result again depends on blending and if color is solid, you'll just overpaint what is already there, just like if depth test is off.

PS. There is not enough data about text issue, I don't see any text there but it looks like you do painting on top of OpenGL's output. Which widget is is, QGLWidget, or QOpenGLWindget? In fact, those two source write into separate passes, and font is draw by Qt using platform-depenadant means, so text might be overwritten? It's not recomended to use Qt's painter output with OpenGL, you may need to look into use of libraries to output text in OpenGL.

Comment: Thank you @Swift, I'm trying to use Z-ordering as you can see in `initializeGL()` I set `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`. Being the problem related to lines and text in transparent textures, I don't matter in which order they are painted, but I expect the the "transparent" part of the texture do not erase lines of other textures as it happens...

Comment: what do you mean for "not enought data about text issue"? Text is painted with a QPainter by: `m_painter.drawText()`. QPainter paint on a QImage that is created upon a buffer. That buffer is the texture I use with `glTexImage2D()` and set onto a GL_QUADS. Can I provide you more information, what may help? Have you seen the issue in the link "text layer issue"?

Comment: @joaulo AH, then it's same problem as with  depth test.. you should create  a texture with transparency - i.e., with alpha component, and use blending mode  when you  paint that quad.  I think, for that you should fill image with transparent color before  printing text.  Formally that's a legit approach to create "texture" text in OpenGL, though  a little slower than something more complex

Comment: @joaulo if you would need to output text on top of OpenGl systematically, try use QGraphics Screne instead, you can insert QOpenGLWinget right into there, while other widgets or graphicscrene objects may overlay it. It's slow but at least tidy way to do that, especially if you want buttons or transparent widgets  on top of graphics. Transparency and z-ordering do not work, you need order things in proper manner. TRansparent color doesn't erase anything, it gets added to color with z below, and so on

Comment: yes, that's what I was actually trying to do. QImage (i.e. texture buffer) is created with `m_img = new QImage(&m_buffer[0], width, height, QImage::Format_RGBA8888);` and then: `m_img->fill(Qt::transparent);`. Blending is handled this way: `glEnable (GL_BLEND); glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` and I've seen that it is also the default for QPainter.